# C++: Unable to change the value of a std::pair using the "=" operator

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to update the value of an `std::pair`, but that results in a compiler error. How can this be resolved?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>> test1;
    test1.insert(std::make_pair(1, std::make_pair("good1", "bad1")));
    test1.insert(std::make_pair(2, std::make_pair("good2", "bad2")));
    test1.insert(std::make_pair(3, std::make_pair("good3", "bad3")));
    test1.insert(std::make_pair(4, std::make_pair("good4", "bad4")));

    std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::const_iterator test2
        = test1.find(1);

    if (test2 == test1.end())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not find test2 in test1\n";
        return 0;
    }

    std::cout << "First item is: " << test2->second.first << "...second item is: " << test2->second.second << "\n";

    /* This line is throwing an error about "No operator '=' matches this operands. */
    test2->second.second = "good";
    
    std::cout << "First item is: " << test2->second.first << "...second item is: " << test2->second.second << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The map setup can be simplified: ....`test1 = { {1, {"good1", "bad1"}}, {2, {"good2", "bad2"}} };`

Comment: "that results in a compiler error" - What error? You're asking for people to volunteer their time to help you so please make it as easy as possible by including the error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `const_iterator` instead of `iterator` for test2:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::const_iterator test2 ...
```

Use:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<std::string, std::string>>::iterator test2 ...
```

Or simplify it using `auto`:

```
auto test2 = test1.find(1);
```